# How to fill SP Online List with Oracle external data

Tags: sharepoint-online, data, connection, oracle

My Problem is make something or configure something to read Oracle DB12 table and fill the Sharepoint 365 List with the retrieved data.
I don't have a Sharepoint On-Premises in my server, So the resolution shouldn't use this kind of Sharepoint environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a C# script that loads data from an 11G Oracle DB to a SharePoint Online list.  It's not a perfect solution by any means, because I have to maintain SP login info for the script to use, and the job has to run on a schedule, but it did the trick for the time being.  I needed these Nuget packages:

Microsoft.SharePoint.Client

Microsoft.SharePointOnline.CSOM

SharePoint

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest that you look at BCS and a external lists.

I have **not** done this with SharePoint Online and I know that there are som limitations compared to on-prem.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I did using WCF webservice. Just crreat an class with a object that has as properties the list collun that you want to shown in exetrnal list. then create a webservice to receive the parametres ( the query paremeters ypou want to pass to oracle); After it create a security store entry to manage the credential you want to use to conect in webservice. In SharePoint design create a new external content type and plug it to your webservice using security stre entry you created before. If everything in ok creat a realist operation to point to your WCF method. I have done this several times in SharePoint OnLine and is OK.