# How to get data from OracleDB to SharePointOnline List

Tags: sharepoint-online, custom-list, migration, database, oracle

I want to migrate data from Oracle DB to SPO list.
What I can think of now is to export the data as a CSV file etc. and paste the data with a quick edit on the SPO list screen.
But this method is very time consuming, inefficient, and unsafe.
Is there any other good way?

Appreciate any ideas\Pointers.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

As an option, you can try to [Connect to an Oracle database in Power BI desktop](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/desktop-connect-oracle-database) and embed the power BI report to a SharePoint Page.

Or you can try to write scripts to do so.

Similar thread here:
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/how-to-import-data-from-oracle-database-to/7e04ec65-aec9-45c7-b276-f661594986f3

[How to fill SP Online List with Oracle external data](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/211109/how-to-fill-sp-online-list-with-oracle-external-data)

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll try that.